# Why do I need to specify the size of this list, else it gives list index out of range error

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to parse a list of urls from a webpage. I did the following things:

1. Got a list of all "a" tags.
2. Used a for loop to `get("href")`
3. While looping, I kept assigning the get value to a new empty list called links

But I kept getting a index out of range error. I thought it might be because of the way I was incrementing the index of links, but I am sure that is not the case.
This is the error prone code:

```
import urllib
import bs4
url = "http://tellerprimer.ucdavis.edu/pdf/"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
webpage = response.read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
i = 0
links = []

for tags in soup.find_all('a'):
    links[i] = str(tags.get('href'))
    i +=1
print i, links
```

I gave links a fixed length and it fixed it, like so:

`links = [0]*89  #89 is the length of soup.find_all('a')`

I want to know what was causing this problem.

Comment: `links.append(str(tags.get('href')))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to assign something to a non-existent index. When you create `links`, you create it as an empty list.

Then you do `links[i]`, but `links` is empty, so there is no `i`th index.

The proper way to do this is:

```
links.append(str(tags.get('href')))
```

This also means that you can eliminate your `i` variable. It's not needed.

---

```
for tags in soup.find_all('a'):
    links.append(str(tags.get('href')))
print links
```

This will print all 89 links in your `links` list.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you. Strange, I have worked with lists before and never got this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The list is initially empty, so you're trying to assign values to non-existing index locations in the list.

Use `append()` to add items to a list:

```
links = []

for tags in soup.find_all('a'):
     links.append(str(tags.get('href')))
```

Or use `map()` instead:

```
links = map(lambda tags: str(tags.get('href')), soup.find_all('a'))
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
links = [str(tags.get('href')) for tags in soup.find_all('a')]
```

Comment: Oh man, map() is so much simpler. I feel so stupid now. But, thank you. Here lambda is just a place holder for a function right?

Comment: `lambda` just lets you specify an anonymous function. You could refer to a named function instead.

Comment: Probably should be able to get rid of the `list()` part. I'll remove it.

Comment: I looked at how `map()` works and I don't know why you have used `lambda tags:` or what it does. Also why is `list()` needed? It works fine without it.